# nesting location.hash to create subviews / subcategories

Tags: javascript, location, hashchange

i can't figure out how to use nested hashes with

```
window.location
```

to have some sort of sub-categories.

```
www.website.com/#!A/#!A1
```

is there a way to store or add the "#!A" fragment with the path, so i can append A1 and/or A2 individually?

Answer (score 0):

You've got all the right terms you need. Try working with

```
window.location.hash
```

You can do things like:

```
var array = window.location.hash.split("/");
array.push("#AB2");
window.location.hash = array.join("/");
```

Or

```
var array = window.location.hash.split("/");
array.pop();
window.location.hash = array.join("/");
```

(You could also do all of this with `substr` or `substring`, but I find working with the arrays a lot easier, and you can compare each piece of the hash as you need it.)